# How is it that a Sharingan can work when it's been transplanted?

Tags: naruto

If the various "superpower" ninja traits are considered "blood traits," how is it someone like Kakashi, who is in no way related to the Uchiha clan, can use the Sharingan Eye technique?

More fully: would transplanting work on *any* bloodline trait power? If someone had a bloodline trait that worked on arms, could they just transplant their arm onto another person and then there would be two people with that technique?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I've the same doubt. According to 2nd Hokage in episode 'NS366 - The All-knowing', Sharingan is the eye that reflect the heart. The unique chakra developed in Brain by the pain of love & disappointment reacting with optical nerves causes the change in appearance of eyes. That unique chakra seems to be a blood-line limit. So to obtain Sharingan for non-Uchiha persons, they should do a heart transplantation; right?!

Answer (score 6):

Let's disregard the fact that eyes in Naruto are considered less difficult to work with than PnP displays. (Rin did it in a cave, without any medical supplies, in a couple of seconds, and it just *worked*)

Your eyes contain your DNA, so our (the Uchiha) eyes contain the already awakened Sharingan, it's written into the DNA.

It also has the genetic information allowing you to activate the techniques the eye holds (including Mangekyo).

Comment: So it doesn't matter who the user is, as long as you feed the eyes chakra it'll just work.

Comment: Yes. It's worth noting that for all cases observed, a transplanted Sharingan cannot go lower than how it was transplanted. (Sharingan can go Mangekyo, but cannot cancel Sharingan, Mangekyo cannot cancel Mangekyo, Rinnegan cannot cancel Rinnegan).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure about other bloodline jutsu, but the Sharingan's power lies within the eye. So whoever controls a Sharingan eye gains its powers.

It may be possible to gain other bloodine jutsu, but to determine where the actual jutsu is located within their body or even the chakra system is still speculation. For now, we know that those jutsu that comes from eyes, Sharingan and Rinnegan are up for grabs, not sure about others though.

Comment: provided that they have enough chakra to 'sustain' it

Answer (score 3):

The Sharingan being transplanted will work, as you've noticed with Kakashi. However it won't be as effective.

Sharingan original users, the Uchiha clan, can use the techniques with ease, but Kakashi needs to rest more often. This is due to the fact that since he's not an Uchiha member, these techniques will use up his chakra much faster.

Kakashi has it all covered, except in battles, because he cannot deactivate it and it would, like I said above, consume his chakra in vain.

He's not the only one that does a transplant. Also,

> Danzo, Tobi transplants the Rinnegan and steals it and Sasuke receives new eyes.

I suspect the same would happen for other transplants but I have no examples off the top of my head.

Comment: I thought Uchiha clan members *did* pay a penalty for Sharingan use, though? Don't they gradually go blind?

Comment: @Alenanno: Mengekyo Sharingan != Hypnotic Sharingan, it literally translates to Kaleidoscopic Sharingan. And it's because each has a different shape and techniques. All Sharingans can hypnotize (cast genjutsu).

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Ah sorry, I was wrong on the translation. I'll repost the comment. But the Mangekyou Sharingan is the only one that provokes blindness.

Comment: @Kasuchiko No. As far as I know, only the Mangekyou Sharingan, will slowly have you lose sight, bringing you to blindness.

Comment: @Alenanno I thought the Uchihas *had* the Mangekyou, not the other one?

Comment: @Kasuchiko Who's the other one? Kakashi? Well, I've not read the Manga but as far as I know, he doesn't possess Mangekyou yet. (You have to acquire it, same as the basic Sharingan.)

Comment: @Alenanno Wait, there's Sharingan eye and the Mangekyou Sharingan eye? It's clearly been a while since I read Naruto. Okay, I think we're on the same page again.

Comment: @Kasuchiko Sharingan is not received by birth: it is awakened after feeling strong emotion/stress. The Mangekyou is awakened in other ways and is harder to achieve (there is a simple way but it's really *bad* in terms of ethics.)

Comment: @Alenanno: Kakashi possesses the Magekyou Sharingan, as shown in the battle against Deidara (who took Gaara that time).

Comment: @looper Yes but not the Mangekyou Sharingan (I was referring to that). Kakashi possesses the Sharingan because Obito did (awoke it like the other members of the Uchiha clan) and now the "eye" does, allowing Kakashi to use it.

Comment: @Alenanno: Edited (forgot the "Magekyou"-part). If I'm remebering correctly, Kakashi tells Naruto that he has a new "Eye-Ability" (I'm not experienced with the terms used in Englisch), the Mangekyo. He also uses it to take Deidaras second arm off and to absorb Deidaras explosion.

Comment: @looper AH! You're right! :O I forgot that. I won't edit it into the answer because it's not part of the question, but you're right.

Comment: Additionally, while you go blind from Mangekyo Sharingan use, you can obtain the Eternal Mangekyo Sharingan by transplanting Mangekyo Eyes from someone who is blood related, mixing the two Mangkeyos and giving additional power. Sasuke gained his EMS by implanting Itachi's eyes, and Madara gained his by implanting Izuna's eyes.

Answer (score 1):

A non-Uchiha cannot advance their Sharingan. As seen with Danzo and Kakashi. The only reason Kakashi had a Mangekyo Sharingan is because Obito saw Rin die.

This is explained by Tobirama when he tells about the Uchiha's brain, how their pain and hate change their brain physiology and functioning, allowing them to turn that pain into the Sharingan. As their pain and hate grow, so does their power.

If a brain isn't an Uchiha brain, and thus does not have this special area of the brain, then they will not:

A.) Naturally gain a Sharingan

B.) Awaken the different stages of the Sharingan.