# Is it possible that Kakashi and Obito are brothers?

Tags: naruto

Is it possible that Kakashi and Obito are brothers? Neither of their mothers are mentioned, and it would explain how Kakashi awakened the Kamui after his eyes were taken.

Comment: Just because their moms are not mentioned, does not mean anything. Also Obito's mom has been mentioned, a little, by his grandmother which said she died alongside her husband, Obito's dad, while protecting him. While on the other hand we know nothing whatsoever about Kakashi's mom, so I guess we either have to assume she died while giving birth to him (that or she died with something else), or just left Kakashi and Sakumo, Kakashi's dad. Which I'm pretty sure she wouldn't do.

Comment: Also, Kakashi and Obito are really close in age, so it would have been hard for the same woman to give birth to them around the same time.

Comment: The only reason Kakashi's Mangekyo awakened was because Obito awakened it when Spoilers:         he saw Rin die.

Answer (score 6):

No, they are not brothers. Obito's sharingan has the ability to use Kamui. Since both Obito and Kakashi share that sharingan, both were able to unlock Kamui.

Obito gives Kakashi his left eye, which has the ability to use long range Kamui. Obito gets to use his right eye, which can only use short range Kamui. That's why Kakashi was able to unlock Kamui. (Specifically the long range variant).

Also, Kakashi is from the Hatake clan, while Obito is from the Uchiha clan.

Comment: Are there any references to long range and short range Kamui? Kakashi is able to use Kamui both at long range (Ex: against Deidara) or even short range (Ex: against Pain and Madara). I think Both are capable of using Kamui at both ranges.

Comment: @VarunRao Obito is best known for using kamui on his own body. You can read about the variations of kamui here:http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kamui

Comment: Wow!! Thanks for the information. I did not know that

Answer (score 3):

Since Kakashi is from Hatake clan and Obito is from Uchiha clan so I don't think they can be brothers.

Also in [wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Kakashi_Hatake) it states that :

> Kakashi teaches the importance of teamwork, a lesson he, like the
>   Sharingan, received from his **childhood friend, Obito Uchiha**.

So its pretty much clear that Obito was Kakashi childhood friend not more than that.

Answer (score 3):

**No, they are not brothers.** Obito is from the Uchiha clan, while Kakashi is from the Hatake clan.

**Furthermore, them being brothers would not explain why Kakashi was able to activate his Sharingan or Mangekyou.**

[Sharingans work even after having been transplanted](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/85/49), and that is why Kakashi was able to use his — however, it is worth noting that it puts much more strain on him than it would on a "native" Sharingan user. As with any other Mangekyou users, [Kakashi's and Obito's Mangekyou were awakened once they experienced great loss of someone close to them](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/4486/49) (Rin, in their case) — it has nothing to do with them being related by blood.